# What does "a sweet gig" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "If a character is immortal — even if it's the "immortal but can die temporarily" type — then their opponents don't need to hold anything back. Not even if those opponents are good guys.
>   IMMORTALITY IS A SWEET GIG. Whether it's because the character can download into a new body as part of a Hive Mind, has a Healing Factor strong enough to reconstruct From a Single Cell, or possesses some even stranger way of staying among the living. The downside is everyone else now considers you fair game for target practice."

What does "a sweet gig" mean here?

Comment: What part don’t you understand?  A gig is a job. Sweet is slang for nice.

Answer (score 3):

According to the *OED*, *sweet* has meant pleasing in general for over a thousand years, so let's turn our attention to *gig*, which has a variety of slang meanings, six according to the *Historical Dictionary of American Slang*. The one of interest is

> business; affair; state of affairs; (*hence*) undertaking or event (1907)

which took on several related shades of meaning, including one's job (1908) -- adopted by pop musicians to mean an engagement to play (1926) --  and from there to one's routine (1970).

So *immortality is a sweet gig* means it's a good thing if events can be arranged so you don't die. Tithonus may disagree.

Answer (score 1):

The English language is considered to be living and breathing, [slowly changing and evolving all the time](http://www.ellenvgregory.com/2012/01/27/get-over-it-english-is-a-living-language). Some people often play with words and give them different meanings which over time become general use definitions.

This is an example of new phrases coming into play.  *A sweet gig* means *nice thing*.

How?

*Sweet*, as pointed out by @Jim is often used as a slang word for *nice*.

Now, it is with the word *gig* where "playing with words" comes in.

*Gig* has a few meanings and one is *job* and job can be a [thing of a specified nature](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/job):

> ‘the car was a blue malevolent-looking job’

Comment: I appreciate your consideration :)